# Can I add my App for Office icon to the ribbon

Tags: excel, icons, ms-office, office-app

We developed an App for Office (Word and Excel) and we have it available for users now. People install it locally but to get to it they need to click so many things (INSERT > My Apps > MY ORGANIZATION > icon...), which is quite frustrating, and difficult to find and remember.

Is there a way to add our icon to the Office Ribbon? Or any other way that will allow single-click launch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an update, it is possible to add button (exactly "commands") to office add-in apps.

Currently supported platforms:

- Office Desktop 2016 (build 16.0.6769.0000 or later)
- Office Online

See [Dev Center](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/add-in-commands-for-excel-and-word-preview) and [git](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/)  .

Answer (score 1):

There is no alternative way unfortunately.